# How to cite comments without copying them to another site?

Tags: support, comments

I would like transfer comments without having to copy it myself.

How to achieve that?

Comment: the datetime stamps at the end of comments are also links. use these to cite the source

Comment: How do I cite the comment?

Comment: i just said, *"the datetime stamps at the end of comments are also links"*, you copy these links

Comment: I think if you notice a yellow query box, it's like template on how to cite it as an mini-Markdown. I tried just straight copying, the time stamp isn't linked to the page made previous

Answer (score 3):

You either have to copy it by hand or link the comment (you can use the timestamp of the comment which serves as link).

So my options would be:

> According to [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/287348/how-to-transfer-comments-without-plagiarizing-to-another-forum#comment932391_287348) you can do this or that.

Or:

> [My comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/287348/how-to-transfer-comments-without-plagiarizing-to-another-forum#comment932391_287348) here says:
>
> > How do I cite the comment?

Comment: So whatever on the answer also applies to the comment

Comment: What do you mean? Yes, you can cite them the same way as answers.

Comment: I actually tried to just cite the author's name, it didn't get referenced, I think its from editing too many times that it doesn't accept any more answers then 5 mins

Comment: You can't do that automatically. You have to do it by hand.

Comment: Ok so I deleted it. It didn't work after the 3rd time; So I have to link the comment by hand again, but when I did, I could not edit it, which apparently accepts it just once before consider permanent?

Comment: After 5 minutes the comment is permanent and only moderators can change it.

Comment: Oh I see only the moderators can

Answer (score 2):

Right-click the comment timestamp and click <kbd>copy link address</kbd> to copy a link to the comment. When you visit that link, the page will scroll down to the comment and it will flash orange.

See the image:

[image]